# Pass filename of the file selected for upload using enctype="multipart/form-data" to a struct field in Golang

Tags: go, filenames, multipart, enctype

My application uses the html code snippet for the form to upload a file

```
<form  method="POST" action="/addproduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label class="form-control-label" for="productimage"></label>
        {{with .Errors.image}}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{.}}
        </div>
        {{end}}     

        <input type="file" name="productimage" id = "productimage" multiple="multiple" class = "btn btn-danger">

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class = "btn btn-info">
    </form>
```

I need to grab the filename of the uploaded file and pass it to a struct field in Golang.

```
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("productimage")
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
    var pimage = header.Filename 

p := &Product{
    Puid:     Puid(),
    Pname:    r.FormValue("productName"),
    Quantity: r.FormValue("quantity"),
    Price:    r.FormValue("price"),
    Image:    pimage,
}
```

I am trying to pass the name of the file selected for uploaded to 'image' field of the struct 'Product'. Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: Thats what you're doing with your code.

Comment: am getting the invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference error though

Comment: Value of filename (pimage) is printed out correctly to the terminal. However I get the error. When I directly assign a string value to the struct field (image) there are no errors. Have tried converting the filename to string, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `r.FormFile()`, you could instead try:

```
mpr, _ := r.MultipartReader()
filePart, _ := r.NextPart()
fileName := filePart.FileName()
```

However, I would check the errors :)

Comment: I am using the govalidator package to validate the struct fields. Filenames with extensions would fail the validation for the alpha and alphanum validator tags and subsequently the error would get generated. I made some changes to escape those validation checks and the code works.